# Handle mutex lock in callback c++

Tags: c++, timer, callback, thread-safety, mutex

I've got a Timer class that can run with both an initial time and an interval. There's an internal function internalQuit performs thread.join() before a thread is started again on the resetCallback. The thing is that each public function has it's own std::lock_guard on the mutex to prevent the data of being written. I'm now running into an issue that when using the callback to for example stop the timer in the callback, the mutex cannot be locked by stop(). I'm hoping to get some help on how to tackle this issue.

```cpp
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(string_view identifier, Function &&timeoutHandler, Duration initTime, Duration intervalTime);
    void start()
    void stop() // for example
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{mutex};
        running = false;
        sleepCv.notify_all();
    }

    void setInitTime()
    void setIntervalTime()
    void resetCallback(Function &&timeoutHandler)
    {
        internalQuit();
        {
            std::lock_guard lock{mutex};
            quit = false;
        }
        startTimerThread(std::forward<Function>(timeoutHandler));
    }

private:
    internalQuit() // performs thread join
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard lock {mutex};
            quit = true;
            running = false;
            sleepCv.notify_all();
        }
        thread.join();
    }

    mainLoop(Function &&timeoutHandler)
    { 
        while(!quit)
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
            // wait for running with sleepCv.wait()
            // handle initTimer with sleepCv.wait_until()
            timeoutHandler(); // callback
            // handle intervalTimer with sleepCv.wait_until()
            timeoutHandler(); // callback
        }
    }

    startTimerThread(Function &&timeoutHandler) 
    {
        thread = std::thread([&, timeoutHandler = std::forward<Function>(timeoutHandler)](){
            mainLoop(timeoutHandler);
        });
    }

    std::thread thread{};
    std::mutex mutex{};
    std::condition_variable sleepCv{}

    // initTime, intervalTime and some booleans for updating with sleepCv.notify_all();
}
```

For testing this, I have the following testcase in Gtest. I'm expecting the timer to stop in the callback. Unfortunately, the timer will hang on acquiring the mutex lock in the stop() function.

```cpp
std::atomic<int> callbackCounter;
void timerCallback() 
{
    callbackCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
}    
TEST(timerTest, timerShouldStopWhenStoppedInNewCallback)
{
    std::atomic<int> testCounter{0};
    Timer<std::chrono::steady_clock > t{"timerstop", &timerCallback, std::chrono::milliseconds(0), std::chrono::milliseconds(100)}; 
    t.resetCallback([&]{
        testCounter += 1;
        t.stop();
    });
    t.start();
    sleepMilliSeconds(100);
    ASSERT_EQ(testCounter.load(), 1); // trigger due to original interval timeout
    sleepMilliSeconds(100);
    ASSERT_EQ(testCounter.load(), 1); // no trigger, because stopped in new callback
}
```

Removing all the mutexes in each of the public fucntions, fixes the issue. But that could lead to possible race conditions for data being written to variables. Hence each function has a lock before writing to f.e. the booleans.

I've tried looking into the std::move functionality to move the thread during the resetCallback into a different variable and then call join on that one. I'm also investigating recursive_mutex but have no experience with using that.

```cpp
void resetCallback(Function &&timeoutHandler)
{
    internalQuit();
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{mutex};
        quit = false;
    }
    auto prevThread = std::thread(std::move(this->thread));
    // didn't know how to continue from here, requiring more selfstudy.
    startTimerThread(std::forward<Function>(timeoutHandler));
}
```

It's a new subject for me, have worked with mutexes and timers before but with relatively simple stuff.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't show how you are calling timer's callback. Probably you are doing it under mutex. This is wrong, you should call callback without mutex locked.

Comment: @sklott I added the info on where the callback is called. This is done in the main loop after a condition_variable.wait_until(lock, duration, [&] { return conditions}) is finished.

Edited: I tried putting the timeouthandler without the mutex lock with the following 


```cpp
lock.unlock();
timeoutHandler();
lock.lock();
```

This causes all tests to pass.

Comment: Yes. This is the way it should be. Since user always can call timer's function which will try to lock mutex. And there is no drawbacks, since user code doesn't access timer's internals.